# Every time I open neovim I need to type in ":source ~/.config/nvim/init.lua"

Tags: windows, neovim

I'm on windows and whenever I open NeoVim it doesn't keep any of my presets unless I type in `:source ~/.config/nvim/init.lua`.

When I tried to add `vim.cmd("source ~/.config/nvim/init.lua")` to my init file it broke and gave me an error. I think it's because I'm using the Unix file location for my init.lua file while I'm on Windows, but I can't figure out how I can change it.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, place your config file in `~/AppData/Local/nvim/`.

See https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html#lua-guide-config